# Conditionally show text on top of an image

Tags: swiftui, overlay, swiftui-zstack

I want to display a list of images. Each image have an associated text, and I want to display that text like a "popover" in style (but how it is achieved is not important - it doesn't have to be as a popover "call"), i.e. on top of the image but only as large as the text actually is, the image is supposed to be seen still in the background around the text.

I have the images in a `HStack` or `VStack`, depending on how the user holds the device and I have a button which I want to use to trigger showing the text. I have tried various ways of adding `.popover` modifier in various places without managing to show anything, including the `Button`. But I haven't gotten it to work in any way.

I'm fairly inexperienced, so the answer might be obvious!

The `GrannyStreamDataItem` data structure uses named images at the moment, but that will of course change later on.

How do I trigger and show the text when the user taps the `i`-button?

```
//Data structure

struct GrannyStreamDataItem: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var image: String
    var comment: String = ""
    var commentPosition: Alignment = .bottomLeading
}

let grannyStreamData: [GrannyStreamDataItem] = [
    GrannyStreamDataItem(image: "Pisa1", comment: "Leaning tower of Pisa. Gosh, it is crowded!", commentPosition: .topLeading),
    GrannyStreamDataItem(image: "Pisa2", comment: "This is what the tower looks like from the inside :-)", commentPosition: .topTrailing),
]


// View showing images 

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            if geometry.size.width > geometry.size.height {
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        HStack {
                            ImageViews(dataItemArray: grannyStreamData)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }

                }
            } else {
                ScrollView(.vertical) {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        VStack {
                            ImageViews(dataItemArray: grannyStreamData)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ImageViews: View {
    let dataItemArray: [GrannyStreamDataItem]
    
    var body: some View { 
        
        ForEach(dataItemArray) { dataItem in
            ZStack(alignment:dataItem.commentPosition) {
                Image(dataItem.image)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                Button {
                    showTextImage(description: dataItem.comment)
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                        .padding(.all, 10)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                //.popover() here won't work... Why not?
                  
            }

        }
    }

    func showTextImage(description: String) {
        print("Image text: \(description)")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Use `popover(isPresented:attachmentAnchor:arrowEdge:content:)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:
I would favor a conditional view to a popover in this case. It has a more flexible appearance.

```
struct ImageList: View {
    let dataItemArray: [GrannyStreamDataItem]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(dataItemArray) { dataItem in
            ImageView(dataItem: dataItem)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            if geometry.size.width > geometry.size.height {
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    HStack {
                        ImageList(dataItemArray: grannyStreamData)
                    }
                    .padding(10)
                }
            } else {
                ScrollView(.vertical) {
                    VStack {
                        ImageList(dataItemArray: grannyStreamData)
                    }
                    .padding(10)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ImageView: View {
    let dataItem: GrannyStreamDataItem
    @State private var showComment: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(dataItem.image)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .overlay(alignment: dataItem.commentPosition) {
                Group {
                    if showComment {
                        Text("Image text: \(dataItem.comment)")
                            .padding(10)
                            .background(.gray.opacity(0.6))
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                            .padding(10)
                    } else {
                        Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                            .padding(10)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                        showComment.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I renamed `ImageViews` to `ImageList` to avoid any name confusion later on.
I removed excessive `HStack`s, `VStack`s and `Spacer`s from `contentView`, they also are more trouble than use.

I moved `Image` and `Text` to a new view `ImageView`. Like that, each of them can have its own `@State` variable `showComment`. This variable can be toggled via an `onTapGesture` and the info image or the comment text will conditionally show. Note the `if`-condition needs to be enclosed by a `Group` view to accept the `onTapGesture` modifier. This Group is enclosed in a `overlay` modifier to stack over the image with the specified alignment.

I also added an animation on the state change to make it a little smoother.

[image]

Comment: Aw, beautiful! :-) Thank you! Just one thing, if you rotate the device to "horizontal" mode, the Text is not confined to the bounds of the Image. Any thoughts of how to do that?

Comment: Hey @Per, I updated my solution to confine the text to the image frame with an `overlay` modifier.

Comment: If this solves your problem, feel free to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Great! I added   .background {
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.clear
                            .onAppear {
                                scaledImageSize = proxy.size
                            }
                    }
                } to the Image (and scaledImageSize is declared @State var scaledImageSize) and to the Text() view I added ".frame(minWidth: 0.0, maxWidth: scaledImageSize.width - 40.0)". The "-40" is to compensate for the two ".padding(10)". Works great! Apart from... see next comment!

Comment: See my updated solution, it works without ` .background { GeometryReader ....` which I found a little convoluted in the end.

Comment: Apart from when the text is only one line long, then the text is display on the whole width of the image, even if the text is just one word. So the .frame() will always be applied as the whole image width. Hmm, can a Text() return its size on screen?

Comment: OK, I'll try your updated solution!